# WCF Service - Call redirect issue

Tags: performance, wcf

We have a WCF service hosted on IIS. The service receives requests and based on one of the request parameters, it either serves the request by itself or redirects it to other server. The process of redirection is essentially a call to another classic web service (asmx).

The issue we have been facing is when I make direct call to the asmx service, we get response in less than 20 ms, however when the same is invoked through the WCF service, the response time shoots to 300ms. My presumption is that the request is being held up somewhere (IIS) before being dispatched to the asmx service from WCF service. I have been trying to check performance counters, however, could not see any counter from which I could conclude anything. I have checked IIS logs as well which also are not very indicative as well.

I have tried to ping the server hosting asmx service from the server hosting wcf service and it takes barely 3ms to get a response back.

Is there any way that could lead me to conclude on to where the extra time is being consumed in the call?

**Update -**
I tried to use Fiddler and it brings down the response time to 20 ms apprx. If I remove fiddler, response time rises to 200 ms

Is there a possiblity that service built in Framework 2.0 when called from Framework 3.5 would respond slow?

**Update 2**
We have narrowed it down to the issue with the proxy. If we turn down the proxy option in fiddler, the response time increases. The call to the WCF service is made on basicHttpBinding which in turn calls asmx service. It looks like Fiddler caches the proxy and reuse it next time. If this understanding is correct, could there be a way to implement similar thing in our setup?

Comment: I would start from profiling WCF service from tools like ANTS Profiler or Visual Studio. Besides, is this happenning for single call or under heavy load?

Comment: This happens for single call as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, our service had expect100Continue set to false. We checked the network transmission using Wireshark which revealed that there is delay in response by the server hosting asmx service when expect100Continue is not appended at the end of the request. 
More on expect100Continue here - 
[expect100Continue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.expect100continue(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Our application needs close to real time performance. After some further discussions, we have decided to set useNagelAlgorithm to false. Keeping expect100Continue could cause issue in load balance environment.